# How to convert Mobile Push List into Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, mobilepush

I have created a list in Mobile Push directly by filtering the contact mobile push attributes.
But am figuring out a way to convert the list into a data extension.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So Mobile lists are DEs (which you can't see in the UI) and you can query them using a query activity. With this you can query the subscriberkey into a target DE which you can leverage elsewhere.

```
Select subscriberkey
From  [name of MobileConnect/MobilePush filtered list name]
```

Other attributes are not accessible through the query activity though

Comment: Too quick for me. Great job @EazyE

Comment: Thanks @EazyE for your help! It's weird that other attributes are not accessible. How we can move from Mobile List to Data extension and capture all attributes in data extension to be used in journey?

Comment: You can access any of the attributes in the journey even if they aren’t in the DE since they are part of the contact model

Comment: Hey @EazyE thanks so much for your response. Is there any way that I can get alI the data from list to data extension?  just needed it to be in data extension because I can select the source as data extension in Journey. If keep it in the List then I can't use it in Journey.

Comment: I still don’t see what your use case to have all the attributes in the  de

Comment: So the use is that, we dont have any contact's now. Let's say if you have downloaded an app then you will come into Mobile Opt-in. Then I will try to send a push notifications via Journey. To send a push via journey i need a data extension as source. That is the reason I was asking if there is any way that we can convert all the attributes of list into data extension?

Comment: two things One you can use a list as an entry source using the audience list: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_audience.htm&type=5  Two I don't understand the use case where you need the attributes in the entry source DE